# How do I make the footer content all in the center of the footer?

Tags: html, css, footer

So the little nav section is at the bottom and the other two sections are at the top of the footer.

Also how would I remove the tiny bit of white space left at the bottom of the page?

Thank you for any help, code is below.

```css
.footer{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 flex-direction: row;
 margin: 0 auto;
 align-items: center;
 background: #000000;
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: -25px;
}
.footer-nav a{
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:#fff;
 position: relative;
}
.mac{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
Okay so now I have it so the copyright and designed by are centered in the middle vertically but the nav buttons are still touching the bottom of the footer.

There is also still white space at the bottom.

HTML
 <div class="footer">
  <nav class='footer-nav'>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <span>Website Designed by <a class='mac' href='https://machooper.com'>Mac Hooper</a></span>
  <span>Copyright &copy Vegan Restaraunt</span>
 </div>
```

Okay so now I have it so the copyright and designed by are centered in the middle vertically but the nav buttons are still touching the bottom of the footer.

There is also still white space at the bottom.

HTML

Okay so now I have it so the copyright and designed by are centered in the middle vertically but the nav buttons are still touching the bottom of the footer.

There is also still white space at the bottom.

HTML
Okay so now I have it so the copyright and designed by are centered in the middle vertically but the nav buttons are still touching the bottom of the footer.

There is also still white space at the bottom.

Should mention that the UL and LI are set to display inline elsewhere in the css.

Comment: I would change those `<span>`s to `<div>`s then `.footer{text-align:center;}` in CSS. I'm not really seeing a reason this should be `display:flex;` without more content. Content will stretch a parent up to its width anyways.

Comment: Okay so now I have it so the copyright and designed by are centered in the middle vertically but the nav buttons are still touching the bottom of the footer.

Comment: If you want to do that you may want to use `.footer{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; }` as `@Obsidian Age` shows. Your issue is that you don't have a height on `.footer`, so there's nothing to center within. You could just add some padding to `.footer` and not use `display:flex;` too, like my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like so

```css
footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0%;
left:20%;
right:20%;

}
/*style*/
footer{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<footer><center><p>Copyright Company 2020 - your date </p> </center></footer>
```

note you can put anything inside the center tag to center it and then the left 20 % mixed with right 20% will push it up increase the %'s to make it
less wide and taller

Comment: Thank you so much for the upvote i'l keep up helping people of course but seriously you didnt have to

Answer (score 1):

You can use `align-items: center` to centralise your items, though I believe you're also looking for `flex-direction: column` to 'align' your items based on their HTML flow. This also has the effect of removing the whitespace at the bottom, as it stems from the `<li>`. This gives separation from the copyright, so I assume this whitespace is *now* intentional.

This combination can be seen in the following:

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-nav a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <nav class='footer-nav'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <span>Website Designed by Mac Hooper</span>
  <span>Copyright &copy Vegan Restaraunt</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Not aligned like that my bad, What I meant was have it all on one horizontal line aligned in the middle in terms of top to bottom

Comment: So, by horizontal, OP really means vertical.

Answer (score 0):

"In the center" meaning everything horizontally centered, below each other?

If yes, add `flex-direction: column;` to stack the items above each other and `align-items: center;` to center them horizontally:

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-nav a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <nav class='footer-nav'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <span>Website Designed by Mac Hooper</span>
  <span>Copyright &copy Vegan Restaraunt</span>
</div>
```

Concerning whitespace (which your code doesn't recreate), you might want to add `margin: 0` to `body` to avoid the default  margin of most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Read my comments then see this:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.footer{
  width:100%; background:silver; text-align:center; padding:50px;
}
nav+div{
  margin-top:7px;
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class='footer'>
  <nav class='footer-nav'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
     <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
     <li><a href='careers.html'>Careers</a></li>
     <li><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>Website Designed by <a class='mac' href='https://machooper.com'>Mac Hooper</a></div>
  <div>Copyright &copy Vegan Restaraunt</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0%;
  left:0%;
  right:0%;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer-nav {
        margin: 10px auto;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
    }

.footer-nav li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0 10px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```